# Final step of finding the determinant not clear

Tags: matrices, determinant

There are two matrices $A_0=\begin{bmatrix}2 & -2 & -4\\-1 & 3 & 4\\1&-2&-3\end{bmatrix}$ and $B_0 = \begin{bmatrix}-4&-3&-3\\1&0&1\\4&4&3\end{bmatrix}$. $B_n = adj(B_{n-1})$, $n \epsilon N$ and I is an identity matrix of order 3. I'm supposed to find $|A_0+A_0^2B_0^2+A_0^3+A_0^4B_0^4+...10$ terms$|$

The solution goes;

[image]

$A_0$ is idempotent, by the way, but that isn't mentioned here.

Everything's fine until the final step, but I can't make out the logic there. How is the final answer suddenly reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factor out $A_0$, then take the determinant.

Comment: Yeah, and it'd be $|A_0(5I + \sum_1^5 B_0^{2n})|$, but what next?

Comment: Determinant of a product (note that $|A_0|=0$).

Comment: Oh, right, got it.